# Blank page on Opera Mini (Extreme Mode Data Saving) using ngrok

Tags: opera, ngrok, opera-mini

I am looking to refactor some apps so that they can render well under Opera Mini using *Extreme Mode* data saving.

To enable me to debug, I am tunnelling my local dev environment to render the app via ngrok for public access but for some reason when I switch to *Extreme Mode* data saving on my Opera Mini app I get a blank page.

Opera Mini App Version: **65.2.2254.63594**

Any pointers on why this could be happening?

Comment: Difficult to say what the problem is, but take a look at https://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-mini-content-authoring-guidelines/#debugging. It shows how you can use various debugging tools to find and fix the problem.

Comment: @perja Thanks for the pointer. I am already using the MicroEmulator to access and test sites under Opera Mini Extreme Data settings and it works for me. What I am looking for is how to render the app from the dev environment since testing on the MicroEmulator via localhost is not possible. Ngrok looks like the best option right now but the page does not render.